# ORM to auto capture real time updates in database

Tags: database, jakarta-ee, caching, orm, real-time

We have a Java based web application to show the status update for the jobs started in last one hour. Jobs status information is maintained MS SQL server 2008. We need to capture the new change added to job status in DB and update the model objects cache in web application server. We are capturing the new updates by periodically making a query to DB and finding the diff in job status.
Is there a better way to capture new updates in DB? Are there any ORM tools available to cache and update this kind of real time data updates? Any suggestions please?

Answer (score 0):

No, and this isn't the job of an ORM.

Unfortunately, Java does not have an equivalent of .NET's Reactive extension (Rx).

You could, however, apply these principles by creating an interface (service) in the web application that the job can talk to. But in most cases, the benefits does not worth the cost to implement it.